# In iframe custom font is not working?

Tags: iframe, font-family

I am facing a problem i have given the custom font. It is working in the website. I have given a iframe in the website and in this iframe custom font is not working it is loading the timer new roman font-family. How to resolve it if anyone have suggestion please share.

Comment: You can't change the css from outside of an iframe.

Answer (score 1):

CSS rules (like the custom font setting) don't cascade through an iframe. One possibility would be to use the new `seamless` attribute:

```
<!doctype html>
<style>
/* custom font etc. */
</style>
<iframe seamless src="http://www.example.org/"></iframe>
<!-- now your styles are inherited by the embed website -->
```

Unfortunately, this attribute has currently very bad browser support, so an easier solution would be to include the relevant stylesheet in the page showed in your iframe.

Comment: @JimiGautam As I mentioned, the `seamless` attribute isn't supported by all browsers yet, so that's why it may be not working. Just include your stylesheet in the document shown in the iframe, too.